# Link to Fontawesome using HTML Inline styling for email

Tags: html, email, font-awesome, inline

I am using iContact, a WYSIWYG email builder that allows for custom HTML blocks.

The client wants a specific shade of grey for social media icons, and iContact uses pngs in only black/white and full color. I can try to use fontawesome social media icons, but I can't access the  tag to link to it.

The option that I tried to no avail was this:

`<script>
        var lNode = document.createElement("link");
        lNode.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        lNode.setAttribute("href", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(lNode)
    </script>`

iContact deletes any  tags, and I don't javascript works in emails anyway.

Is there a way to link to a font using HTML inline styling, or should I just use black and white icons and tell them it's the only way?

Answer (score 1):

I just used a workaround by using Adobe Illustrator to turn the font-awesome icons into pngs.